# How to display information from Ajax POST request in aspx?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a simple js code in a C# asp .net page that aims to get a signature and send its data to be inserted into a database.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;

        // Spec canvas dimensions
        canvas.width = 700;
        canvas.height = h / 2.5;

        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
            dotSize: 1
        });

        document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            if (!signaturePad.isEmpty()) {

                // Gets img data and split it to server
                var imageURI = signaturePad.toDataURL();
                var encoded_image = imageURI.split(',');
                var img_to_server = encoded_image[1];

                $.ajax({
                    url: "About.aspx/",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: { image: img_to_server },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        window.alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        window.alert('no success');
                    }
                });
            }
        }, false);
```

That page loads properly and I send the POST request to another page of my application: About.aspx
On that page I want to get the value sent to use it in a query, but I can't find a way to store it in a variable

```
    public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Inside");
        string val = Request.Params["image"];
        Debug.WriteLine(val);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is a really bad name for a parameter...

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling a method that returns a value? I don't see any returns anywhere.

Comment: Just FYI - I wouldn't use a web page to catch and respond to that POST request. A WebAPI controller method would probably be more appropriate. That way it can more easily respond with JSON to your ajax call, you can more easily limit to POST, etc.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Even if i make it a returnable method I don't have the POST data to return it properly..

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the uploaded file with :

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];
```